# How to start with Mifare Desfire

Tags: android, nfc, mifare

I finished reading a book about smart cards that provided me a good overview. On the other hand there was no code and I feel weak in this regard.

For my application I want to use Mifare Desfire and it needs to:

- User must provide the PIN to use it
- Implement Internal Authenticate (to avoid replay attacks)
- Read the stored key

I don't have a USB reader yet, but I can write the tags with my Nexus and [IsoDep](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/IsoDep.html).

Can you point me to the right direction? What tools should I use? What are the supported commands?

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to start with [this](http://ridrix.wordpress.com/2009/09/19/mifare-desfire-communication-example/) and [this](http://neteril.org/files/M075031_desfire.pdf).

Comment: Thanks, this is useful. For some reason i could not find the pdf liked!